# ASP.NET upload image to db and display image from DB in image slider form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database, image, slider

I am now using visual studio to making a web site.
My goal is to upload image to DB(not local DB in ASP.net) and display images from that DB.
The most important thing here is images should be shown in image slider form.

Now I already finished uploading image to DB and display image using dataTable.
Also, seperately, I found a good code for image slider. 
However, using that code(image slider) I only can display images in the local folder not Database.

So I am wondering whether it is possible to connect those to code?
I attached two code.

**http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1010313/Image-Slider-From-Folder-Without-Database-in-MVC**
-> this one is image slider

and below is code for uploading image to DB and showing it in the dataTable

**(handler.ashx)**

```
            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
               string connectionString = "";
               MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection    (connectionString); 
               myConnection.Open(); 
               string sql = "Select Content, ContentType from table where FileId=@FileId";
               MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileId", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = context.Request.QueryString["id"]; 
               cmd.Prepare(); 
               MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
               dr.Read(); 
               context.Response.ContentType = dr["ContentType"].ToString(); 
               context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Content"]); 
               dr.Close();
               myConnection.Close(); 
            }

            public bool IsReusable
            {
                get
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

**(webform.aspx)**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="upload" OnClick="UploadFile"/>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Id" DataField="FileId" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Name" DataField="FileName" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Image">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" ImageUrl='<%#"Handler.ashx?id=" + Eval("FileId")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**(webform.aspx.cs)**

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = FetchAllImagesInfo();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
            using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "INSERT INTO table(FileName, ContentType, Content) VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Content)";
                        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", filename);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    public DataTable FetchAllImagesInfo() 
     { 
       MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from table", "Data Source=;"); 
       DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
       da.Fill(dt); 
       return dt; 
     }
}
```

If it is hard to combine those two, 
it is also pretty okay to let me know method

below is the code for slider
and with this, it is not connected to DB, it just upload picture without using DB  but what I want to do is uploading image to db and show that from DB in image slider format

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bjqs.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?     family=Source+Code+Pro|Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
     <h2>Image slider</h2>

     <div id="banner-fade">
      <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
                <ul class="bjqs">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval Container.DataItem,"Value") %>' title='<%# (DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"Text").ToString()).Split('.')[0].ToString() %>' alt=""></li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
                <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

            </div>
             <script class="secret-source" style="display:none;">
                 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                     $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
                         height: 320,
                         width: 620,
                         responsive: true
                     });

                 });
      </script>
    </div>
     <script src="js/libs/jquery.secret-source.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(function ($) {

                $('.secret-source').secretSource({
                    includeTag: false
                });

            });
    </script>
    </form>

   </body>

   </html>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace _imageslider
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "img/" + fileName));
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = files;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get error messages? Where is your Slider code?

Comment: @Alexander  for image slider i use code from "http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1010313/Image-Slider-From-Folder-Without-Database-in-MVC " the problem is that I cannot combine those two things.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Alexander I attached additional code below

Comment: @Alexander what I want to do is uploading image to db and show that from DB in image slider form. And i just can upload image to DB, but I don't know the way to display it in slider form

Comment: Can you actually read and understand your(?) code? And, why do you want to store images in the database in the first place?

Comment: @Alexander oh now I check this comment,  I pretty understand what I am doing now with database, but I the problem was I have no idea with slider.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks to your comment, now I am trying to change my code, and it's pretty better than before

Answer (score 0):

In `Page_Load`, your(?) code is reading all images from folder `img`, and writes the paths into a List. That List is bound to the Repeater, and the Repeater creates `<img>` tags with the supplied paths.

You must change the HTML markup to point to your handler.ashx, instead of a path, and change the `Page_Load` accordingly.

Comment: Oh... I understand what you mean,

Comment: However, the problem is that I don't know the way to change so.. that's the problem

Comment: Well then I'm afraid you have to dig yourself into the code and understand what's written in front of you. It'll be a minor change, and I'm sure sooner or later somebody will post the line necessary without comment. But you have to evolve from copy-pasting code from different websites to understanding what you are doing.